# vba code for generating a report in worksheet then save in pdf

Tags: vba, report

I am pasting here my working code which generate report in worksheet then save it in pdf format then open it in pdf after selecting a name from a combobox in userform then press commandbutton1 to execute it.

Source worksheet2 (RpT)
Target worksheet5 (Ptr)

all do well but it is a long code which takes time to perform so any idea to reduce it in a smart way. Any expert brother can re-code it for me?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Double 'Long
Dim final As Integer

Me.Hide
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Rpt").Visible = True
Worksheets("Rpt").Unprotect "Hakeem"

On Error Resume Next

For i = 11 To 65000
If Sheet2.Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
final = i - 1
Exit For
End If
Next

For i = 11 To final
If PUF5r.ComboBox1 = Sheet2.Cells(i, 2) Then
Sheet5.Range("L9") = "=TODAY()"
Sheet5.Range("L4") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) 'PtR No
Sheet5.Range("D13") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 2) 'Pt Name
Sheet5.Range("C14") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 3) 's/o d/o w/o
Sheet5.Range("D14") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 4) 'Relative Name
Sheet5.Range("D15") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 5) 'Phone
Sheet5.Range("L14") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 6) 'Reg Date
Sheet5.Range("D16") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 9) 'Symptoms
Sheet5.Range("H15") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 10) 'Tehreak
Sheet5.Range("M16") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 14) 'T. visits
Sheet5.Range("$K$19") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 10) 'PIN (Tehreak, Pulse indication No)
'specialy following this piece of code shoud be reduce.
Sheet5.Range("$C$19") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 6) 'Trmnt dt1 
Sheet5.Range("$D$19") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 11) 'Trmnt1
Sheet5.Range("$L$19") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 12) 'For Days1
Sheet5.Range("$M$19") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 13) 'Food Plan1
Sheet5.Range("$C$21") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 19) 'Trmnt dt2
Sheet5.Range("$K$21") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 20) 'PIN2
Sheet5.Range("$D$21") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 21) 'Trmnt2
Sheet5.Range("$L$21") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 22) 'For Days2
'Sheet5.Range("$M$21") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 13) 'Food Plan2
Sheet5.Range("$C$23") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 23) 'Trmnt dt3
Sheet5.Range("$K$23") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 24) 'PIN3
Sheet5.Range("$D$23") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 25) 'Trmnt3
Sheet5.Range("$L$23") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 26) 'For Days3
Sheet5.Range("$C$25") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 27) 'Trmnt dt4
Sheet5.Range("$K$25") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 28) 'PIN4
Sheet5.Range("$D$25") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 29) 'Trmnt4
Sheet5.Range("$L$25") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 30) 'For Days4
Sheet5.Range("$C$27") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 31) 'Trmnt dt5
Sheet5.Range("$K$27") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 32) 'PIN5
Sheet5.Range("$D$27") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 33) 'Trmnt5
Sheet5.Range("$L$27") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 34) 'For Days5
Sheet5.Range("$C$29") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 35) 'Trmnt dt6
Sheet5.Range("$K$29") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 36) 'PIN6
Sheet5.Range("$D$29") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 37) 'Trmnt6
Sheet5.Range("$L$29") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 38) 'For Days6
Sheet5.Range("$C$31") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 39) 'Trmnt dt7
Sheet5.Range("$K$31") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 40) 'PIN7
Sheet5.Range("$D$31") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 41) 'Trmnt7
Sheet5.Range("$L$31") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 42) 'For Days7
Sheet5.Range("$C$33") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 43) 'Trmnt dt8
Sheet5.Range("$K$33") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 44) 'PIN8
Sheet5.Range("$D$33") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 45) 'Trmnt8
Sheet5.Range("$L$33") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 46) 'For Days8
Sheet5.Range("$C$35") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 47) 'Trmnt dt9
Sheet5.Range("$K$35") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 48) 'PIN9
Sheet5.Range("$D$35") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 49) 'Trmnt9
Sheet5.Range("$L$35") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 50) 'For Days9
Sheet5.Range("$C$37") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 51) 'Trmnt dt10
Sheet5.Range("$K$37") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 52) 'PIN10
Sheet5.Range("$D$37") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 53) 'Trmnt10
Sheet5.Range("$L$37") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 54) 'For Days10
Sheet5.Range("$C$39") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 55) 'Trmnt dt11
Sheet5.Range("$K$39") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 56) 'PIN11
Sheet5.Range("$D$39") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 57) 'Trmnt11
Sheet5.Range("$L$39") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 58) 'For Days11
Sheet5.Range("$C$41") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 59) 'Trmnt dt12
Sheet5.Range("$K$41") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 60) 'PIN12
Sheet5.Range("$D$41") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 61) 'Trmnt12
Sheet5.Range("$L$41") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 62) 'For Days12
Sheet5.Range("$C$43") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 63) 'Trmnt dt13
Sheet5.Range("$K$43") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 64) 'PIN13
Sheet5.Range("$D$43") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 65) 'Trmnt13
Sheet5.Range("$L$43") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 66) 'For Days13
Sheet5.Range("$C$45") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 67) 'Trmnt dt14
Sheet5.Range("$K$45") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 68) 'PIN14
Sheet5.Range("$D$45") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 69) 'Trmnt14
Sheet5.Range("$L$45") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 70) 'For Days14

Sheet5.Range("$L$49") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 15) 'T Bills amount
Sheet5.Range("$L$50") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 16) 'Rcvd
Sheet5.Range("$L$51") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 17) 'Bal
Sheet5.Range("$C$50") = Sheet2.Cells(i, 18) 'Pt Status
Exit For
End If
Next
Worksheets("Rpt").Protect "Hakeem", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
Worksheets("Rpt").EnableSelection = xlNoSelection

Worksheets("Rpt").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ Tib_e_Sabir" & " Report of " & Worksheets("Rpt").Range("$D$13").Value _
        , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
        'MsgBox "PDF file has been created and saved in ""TibSabir"" folder:"
PUF5rI.Show
'Call stopdf 'es code ko theek karna hey.
'Unload Me
'PUF0.Show
'Sheet2.Activate
'''Sheet5.Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: How long does it take?

Comment: If your code is working, but you want code-review, then consider posting your question here - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: about 3 to 5 seconds but some time it takes more then 5 seconds.

Comment: Ok, I have created an account at codereview.stackexchange.com just now and posting my code for a review there.